# How can I call a django model function in a graphene resolver?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have model with `getQuality` function defined in it.

Graphql type is

```
class Person(DjangoObjectType):
   class Meta:
      model = PersonModel

   quality = graphene.String()

   def resolve_quality(self, info):
      person = PersonModel.objects.get(pk = self.id)
      return person.getQuality()
```

This might work but I will be querying the same object twice. How can I call a model function in  a resolver?

Answer (score 3):

```
class Person(DjangoObjectType):
   class Meta:
      model = PersonModel

   quality = graphene.String()

   def resolve_quality(self, info):
      return self.getQuality()
```